# Excel not accepting data from PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, outlook

I'm using PowerShell to data mine my outlook email and then export that data to an excel worksheet. I want to get each email's subject, sender name, and received time. I can get all three from outlook but when I export the data to excel PowerShell throws an error exception for the sender name and received time. The code section in question is my foreach statement:

```
$i = 0
foreach($item2 in $mail)
{

#$item2 | select subject // each of these displays the correct information in PowerShell
#$item2 | select senderName
#$item2 | select ReceivedTime

$item3 = $item2 | Select-Object -Property senderName // Copies senderName to a new variable
Write-Output $item3 // Successfully displays senderName

$Data.Cells.Item($i, 2) = $item2 // No issues, data is successfully export to excel
$Data.Cells.Item($i, 3) = $item3 // Throws exception when I try to export $item3
$i++;
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At C:\Users\Tower\Documents\testingMail.ps1:45 char:5
+     $Data.Cells.Item($i, 3) = $item3
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Full Code:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$MyFolder1 = $namespace.Folders.Item('YOUREMAIL@EMAIL.COM').Folders.Item('Inbox')
$rules = $namespace.DefaultStore.GetRules()
$rule = $rules.create("My rule1: Receiving Notification",[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuleType]::olRuleRecieve) 


$mail = $namespace.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Item(2).Folders.Item(1).Items

$Path = 'C:\Users\Tower\Documents\mail.xlsx'

$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $True
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($Path)
$i = 1
$workbook.Worksheets.Add()
$Data= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$i = 0
foreach($item2 in $mail)
{

#$item2 | select subject // each of these displays the correct information in PowerShell
#$item2 | select senderName
#$item2 | select ReceivedTime

$item3 = $item2 | Select-Object -Property senderName // Copies senderName to a new variable
Write-Output $item3 // Successfully displays senderName

$Data.Cells.Item($i, 2) = $item2 // No issues, data is successfully export to excel
$Data.Cells.Item($i, 3) = $item3 // Throws exception when I try to export $item3
$i++;
}
```

Comment: What's a sample value of `$item3`?

Comment: In powershell, the output is: SenderName : Example Name. In excel, it should, in theory, only display "Example Name"

Comment: `//` is **not** the comment marker in PowerShell.. (that's for C#). Use a hash symbol `#` instead. Also give your variables more descriptive names to avoid confusion later. Plus you need `Select-Object -ExpandProperty senderName` to get just the string value, not an object with that property. Excel won't understand that.